Ways to parametrise a positive parameter
I am working with a differentiable state-space model involving a noise variance term $\sigma^2$ which I want to parametrise based on some features, e.g. $\sigma^2 = g(X\beta) > 0$, wherer $\beta$ are learnable paremeters. So far I am using $g=\exp$ (features at the moment are just categorical, but with meaningful numerical features this would become nonsensical), which is causing me problems. At small (large -ve) values of $X \beta $, gradients are tiny, and gradients explode for large values. Optimising with L-BFGS, I find that the optimisation is sensitive to initial conditions and can sometimes try extreme values that cause overflow errors (e.g. a variance of 10 leads to huge state values).
Is there a smarter/more standard way of dealing with this sort of setup? I have considered:

Relu link, but this is very likely to hit zero grads
Leaky relu, but this has no guarantee of keeping variances positive
Softplus link, but this suffers from the same small-gradients problem in the left tail where it is exponential.
Parametrising $g(x) = x^2$, i.e. $\sigma = |X \beta|$. This seems to work well, but I am wary of it in more complex models, as a non-injective link function seems like it could lead to nonsensical additive effects and cause the optimiser to "bounce around" a minimum.

I could not find any examples in literature of modelling a variance explicitly like this, would appreciate any insights.

Is it feasible to work with $\log \sigma^2$ instead? The quantity $\log \sigma^2$ can be positive or negative, so you wouldn't have to worry about the positivity constraint.
